# Context Free Grammar for Try-Catch-Finally Statement and Throw

Tags: formal-grammars, parsers

I am currently working on a problem that is asking me to write the grammar productions for the try-catch-finally and throw C# statements. It states that "you can assume that there are nonterminals "Type", "Expression", and "Statement", as well as a terminal "Ident". I do not understand how this is possible using so few nonterminals and only one terminal

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need more terminals, for the reserved words `try`, `catch`, `finally`, and `throw`, and possibly for braces and for semicolon (depending on the interpretation of *Statement*).

Here is an example to help you get started. It gives the syntax of a simple if statement, assuming that *Statement* also includes compound statements (i.e. `{ ... }`), and that statements do not end in a semicolon.

IfStatement → **if** **(** Expression **)** Statement